# Facebook SDK iOS 6.1.4 not working

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk

I have a problem with the facebook login using my ios app.

My application work fine with all iOS version, only with the iOS 6.1.4, i don't know why !
In the iOS 6.1.4 when i click on the login button, the system open the facebook app, and then I need to back to my app manually.

Any one have an idea ?

Comment: Double check your app plist contains URL Schemes entity of your unique facebook API Key

Comment: yes it's contains the URL Schemes fbxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I need to upgrade my facebook sdk from 3.2 to 3.5

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/

And it works perfectly.